# How can I restart model.fit after x epochs if loss remains high?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having trouble sometimes getting a fit on my data, and when I restart fit (with shuffle=true) then I sometimes get a good fit.

See my previous question:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/62516/why-does-my-model-sometimes-not-learn-well-from-same-data

As a **work around**, I want to automatically restart the fitting process, if loss is high after x epochs. How can I achieve this?

I assume I would need to use a custom version of EarlyStopping callback? How could I differentiate between ES because of finding a low loss ( < 0.5) so training is finished, or because loss > 0.5 after x epochs so need to restart training?

Here is a simplified structure:

```
def train_till_good():
    while not_finished:
         train()

def train():
    load_data()
    model = VerySimpleNet2(); 

    checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=images_root + dataset_name + '\\CheckPoint.hdf5')

    myOpt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001,decay=0.01)

    model.compile(optimizer=myOpt, loss='categorical_crossentropy',  metrics=['accuracy'])

   LRS = CyclicLR(base_lr=0.000005, max_lr=0.0003, step_size=200.)

    tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='C:\\Tensorflow', histogram_freq=0,write_graph=True, write_images=False)

    ES = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=5)

    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, shuffle=True, epochs=num_epochs,
              callbacks=[checkpoint,
                         tensorboard,
                         ES,
                         LRS],
              validation_data = (test_images, test_labels)
              )


def VerySimpleNet2():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(112, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
        keras.layers.Flatten(),
        keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])
    return model
```

Comment: Will you chang some hyperparams when restart model fit?

Comment: No. I don't change anything between re-fitting. The ONLY thing that changes is that model.fit(shuffle-true) will shuffle the Training data.